# Prevent App Engine hot reload on change in PyCharm .idea folder

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dev-appserver

The App Engine local dev server reloads every time there's a change to files - which is cool. What's uncool is that it also reloads on changes in .idea folder of the PyCharm editor, cluttering the logs. Tried adding this to `app.yaml`:

`skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
- ^\.idea$ # added this line in order to try and ignore .idea folder on build`

This didn't help. Still rebuilds every time I do arbitrary stuff in the editor (not changing any code).

How can I tell App Engine dev server which folder to ignore for hot reload?

Comment: Try "^\.idea*$" maybe?

Answer (score 0):

`dev_appserver.py --help` mentions:

```
--watcher_ignore_re WATCHER_IGNORE_RE
                        Regex string to specify files to be ignored by the
                        filewatcher. (default: None)
```

In this case this is related to `dev_appserver.py`, which will detect changes in local `app.yaml` and reload local server, while `app.yaml` running in GAE is not supposed to do because reloading is done by `gcloud app deploy`.

Comment: This looked exactly like what I need, except for the fact that it's not working. Provided any possible expression I could think of - no effect. Event tried `.*` keeps working as usual (not ignoring anything).

Comment: What version are you using? The [resent version](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-compat-runtime/blob/743ade7e1350c790c4aaa48dd2c0893d06d80cee/appengine-compat/exported_appengine_sdk/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/watcher_common.py#L71) seems to ignore all files starting with the dot(_IGNORED_PREFIX == '.').

Comment: the link is leading to a deprecated version of what is now called the "flexible environment". I'm using standard environment.

Comment: Can you share with me how exactly you where using `--watcher_ignore_re`?

In any case I have installed `dev_appserver.py` following [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/download) instructions using `gcloud components install app-engine-python`. Version 1.9.64.



When I browse the code I see that everything starting from '.' is ignored. And for me .idea is never detected.

Comment: Note that GAE's file watcher code is different on Mac, Linux, and Windows, so when discussing it, it helps to specify what system you're running on.